# URL Parameters in MVCReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

As you know, In SQL Server reporting service (SSRS), We can pass the parameters with URL ([URL Access Syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154042(v=sql.105).aspx)) and we can provide data source credentials in a URL by including the dsu:datasourcename=value & dsp:datasourcename=value ([Setting Data Source Credentials in a URL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154640(v=sql.105).aspx)).

Now, I want to open a report in my web application with dynamic data source credencial.
I'm using [MVCReportViewer](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer) and when I set the `MvcReportViewerFluent:ReportServerUrl` parameter as `http://ServerName/reportserver/?dsu:myDS=user&dsp:myDS=password`, I get the blank page in iFrame.

When I remove `"/?dsu:myDS=user&dsp:myDS=password"`, The report work correctly and ask user name and password inside the report.
Where am I going wrong?

**Edit: Codes Added**

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new {
        UserName = "user",
        Password = "pass",
        ReportPath = "/myReportPath",
        ServerUrl = "http://ServerAddress/reportserver/?dsu:ddst=pdm&dsp:ddst=pdm",
        Parameters = null,
        FormMethod = FormMethod.Post,
        HtmlAttributes = new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none" }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

View Code:

```
@Html.MvcReportViewerFluent(Model.ReportPath)
     .ReportServerUrl(Model.ServerUrl)
     .Username(Model.UserName)
     .Password(Model.Password)
     .Method(Model.FormMethod)
     .ReportParameters(Model.FormMethod)
     .Attributes(Model.HtmlAttributes).
```